Проведение документа 1С OData
Всем привет! Создаю заказ через OData, документ создается но не проводится, как его провести?
Вот мой код:
data = {
  "БанковскийСчет_Key": "47a25ef9-402a-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44",
  "ВалютаДокумента_Key": "c26a4d87-c6e2-4aca-ab05-1b02be6ecaec",
  "ВариантЗавершения": "Успешно",
  "ВидЗаказа": "6d8cc37d-6ae7-11ed-91a8-a068f8f3337c",
  "ВидЗаказа_Type": "StandardODATA.Catalog_ВидыЗаказовПокупателей",
  "ВидимостьИндикатораТребуетсяРасчет": True,
  "ВидОперации": "ЗаказНаПродажу",
  "ВидЦен_Key": "ff235c55-6ae6-11ed-91a8-a068f8f3337c",
  "ВидЭлектронногоДокумента": "ОтветНаЗаказ",
  "Договор_Key": "d97d9256-440d-11ef-a2ee-00155d550200",
  "ИдентификаторПлатежа": "ЗКП240700НФ000001005",
  "Контрагент_Key": "d97d9257-440d-11ef-a2ee-00155d550200",
  "Кратность": "1",
  "Курс": 1,
  "НалогообложениеНДС": "НеОблагаетсяНДС",
  "НДСВключатьВСтоимость": True,
  "НоменклатураДоставки_Key": "82073005-4040-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44",
  "ОжидаемаяДатаВручения": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
  "ОжидаетсяВыборВариантаКП": False,
  "Организация_Key": "54f8b74a-4029-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44",
  "ОснованиеПечати": "Основной договор",
  "ОснованиеПечатиСсылка": "d97d9256-440d-11ef-a2ee-00155d550200",
  "ОснованиеПечатиСсылка_Type": "StandardODATA.Catalog_ДоговорыКонтрагентов",
  "ОсновнойВариантКП": 0,
  "Ответственный_Key": "54f8b751-4029-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44",
  "ПодписьГлавногоБухгалтера_Key": "47a25ef7-402a-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44",
  "ПодписьРуководителя_Key": "47a25ef7-402a-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44",
  "ПоложениеВидаРабот": "ВШапке",
  "ПоложениеДатыОтгрузки": "ВШапке",
  "ПоложениеСклада": "ВШапке",
  "ПочтаПолучателя": "",
  "ПричинаОтмены_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "Проект_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "ПроцентСкидкиПоДисконтнойКарте": 0,
  "ПунктВыдачиЗаказа_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "СкидкиРассчитаны": True,
  "СлужбаДоставки_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "Событие_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "СостояниеЗаказа": "73a41484-6ae7-11ed-91a8-a068f8f3337c",
  "СостояниеЗаказа_Type": "StandardODATA.Catalog_СостоянияЗаказовПокупателей",
  "СпециальныйНалоговыйРежим": "НеПрименяется",
  "СписокНоменклатуры": "",
  "СписокРесурсов": "",
  "СпособДоставки": "Самовывоз",
  "СпособЗачетаПредоплаты": "Вручную",
  "СпособОтгрузки": "",
  "СпособРасчетаСебестоимостиКалькуляции": "",
  "СпособРасчетаСебестоимостиКалькуляции_Type": "StandardODATA.Undefined",
  "СтавкаНДСДоставки_Key": "73a41495-6ae7-11ed-91a8-a068f8f3337c",
  "Старт": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
  "СтоимостьДоставки": 0,
  "СтруктурнаяЕдиницаПродажи_Key": "ff235c57-6ae6-11ed-91a8-a068f8f3337c",
  "СтруктурнаяЕдиницаРезерв_Key": "47a25ef0-402a-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44",
  "СуммаВключаетНДС": True,
  "СуммаНДСДоставки": 0,
  "Телефон": "",
  "ТипДенежныхСредств": "Безналичные",
  "ТрекНомер": "",
  "УдалитьЗакрыт": False,
  "УдалитьИспользоватьФаксимиле": "",
  "УсловияГарантийногоТалона_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "УсловияКоммерческогоПредложения_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "УчитыватьВНУ": True,
  "Финиш": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
  "ШаблонКалькуляции_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "Ширина": 0,
  "Ячейка_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "РасчетКалькуляцииПоДаннымТЧ": False,
  "СебестоимостьДоставки": 0,
  "СсылкаДляОплаты": "",
  "СозданИзКабинетаКлиента": False,
  "СервисДоставки": "",
  "УчетПотребностиПоСкладам": False,
  "УчетПотребностиПоЗаказам": True,
  "ЭтоУниверсальныйДокумент": False,
  "Водитель_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "Автомобиль_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "Прицеп_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "Перевозчик_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "СтатусСборки": 0,
  "ДатаВходящегоДокумента": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
  "ДатаИзменения": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
  "ДатаОтгрузки": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
  "ДоверенностьДата": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
  "Date": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
  "Запасы": [
    {
      "LineNumber": "1",
      "ТипНоменклатурыЗапас": True,
      "Номенклатура": "6831eb5d-4fc9-11ef-a320-000ec6c817c0",
      "Номенклатура_Type": "StandardODATA.Catalog_Номенклатура",
      "Характеристика_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "СерииНоменклатуры": "",
      "Резерв": 0,
      "РезервОтгрузка": 0,
      "ЕдиницаИзмерения": "6d8cc3fe-6ae7-11ed-91a8-a068f8f3337c",
      "ЕдиницаИзмерения_Type": "StandardODATA.Catalog_КлассификаторЕдиницИзмерения",
      "Цена": 25245,
      "ПроцентСкидкиНаценки": 0,
      "СуммаСкидкиНаценки": 0,
      "СтавкаНДС_Key": "73a41495-6ae7-11ed-91a8-a068f8f3337c",
      "СуммаНДС": 0,
      "ДатаОтгрузки": "2024-08-01T00:00:00",
      "Спецификация_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Содержание": "",
      "ПроцентАвтоматическойСкидки": 0,
      "СуммаАвтоматическойСкидки": 0,
      "Количество": 1,
      "КлючСвязи": "1",
      "СтранаПроисхождения_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "НомерГТД_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Партия_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Вес": 8,
      "Объем": 0,
      "НомерВариантаКП": 0,
      "ЭтоРазделитель": False,
      "НоменклатураНабора_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "ХарактеристикаНабора_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "ДоляСтоимости": "0",
      "СтруктурнаяЕдиницаРезерв_Key": "47a25ef0-402a-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44",
      "Ячейка_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "КоличествоСобрано": 0,
      "ПрослеживаемыйТовар": False,
      "КодТНВЭД_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "ИдентификаторСтроки": "",
      "ПрослеживаемыйКомплект": False,
      "ПродажаПодарка": False
    }
  ]
}

create(entity='Document_ЗаказПокупателя', data=data, username='Nick', password='')

